# How to disable replay XHR programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, angular, browser, xmlhttprequest

I have a asp.net core web api with angular.. I need a way to disable or hide the replay xhr which is being showed in the network tab.. how to proceed? and an insight of any issues/problems if we have replay xhr in the browser would be helpful

Disabling or hiding the replay xhr is the expectation

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: For security purposes

Comment: It will not improve security in any imaginable way